# When can binding a form element to jQuery's change and input events along with DOMNodeInserted cause IE browsers to crash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, infinite-loop, jquery-events

I am looking at some code which has an HTML text area...

```
<div class="favorites">
   <textarea id="favoriteSinger"></textarea>
</div>
```

On DOM ready (page load) this element has the jQuery input and change events bound to it like so...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var myTextArea = $("#favoriteSinger");
  myTextArea.bind("change input", function () {
        console.debug("Why does IE keep calling me?");
  }
```

Later down in the code they are also doing....

```
 $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.favorites', function () {
  $('.favorites #favoriteSinger').html('Who is your favorite singer?');
  $('.favorites #favoriteSinger').attr('style', '');
});
```

This code works fine in all browsers except IE 9 and above which keeps calling the change/input event handler and eventually crashes.

Can someone take a gander as to what would make IE behave in such a way?

Comment: *"which keeps calling that event handler and eventually crashes"* - Do you mean that when the user changes the field *once* the handler is somehow called multiple times in some kind of loop? If so, well, the code you actually show does *not* exhibit that behaviour so obviously something in the code not shown is causing the problem. Is there a minimal example you can show where that behaviour occurs?

Comment: I think you need to take this one, up to jQuery team.  Don't forget to mention what jQ version was it.

Comment: This is happening at page load, before any user action. Like I said there is a lot of other code messing with that element, and as you said, something in the code not shown is causing the problem. And that is exactly what I am looking for, but its hard to find because there is so much code. Any suggestions on what to look for?